# Difference between alsamixer and amixer's output about the percentage of Master

Tags: command-line, alsa

I'm trying to write a bash script to find the percentage of the sound volume. I used this:

```
amixer get Master | awk '/Mono.+/ {print $6=="[off]"?$6:$4}'
```

This command prints the volume percentage of `Master` channel, or prints `[off]` if it's muted.

However, as you can see from screenshot below, the percentage that `amixer get Master` outputs is different from the percentage that `alsamixer` shows in the `Master` channel.

[image]

What's the difference? Which one is the real percentage of my `Master` channel? How can I get the percentage that `alsamixer` shows (if it's the real one)?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

From [`man 1 alsamixer`](https://linux.die.net/man/1/alsamixer):

> Volume Mapping
>
> In `alsamixer`, the volume is mapped to a value that is more natural for a human ear. The mapping is designed so that the position in the interval is proportional to the volume as a human ear would perceive it, i.e. the position is the cubic root of the linear sample multiplication factor. For controls with a small range (24 dB or less), the mapping is linear in the dB values so that each step has the same size visually.
>
> Only for controls without dB information, a linear mapping of the hardware volume register values is used (this is the same algorithm as used in the old `alsamixer`).

Then from [`man 1 amixer`](https://linux.die.net/man/1/amixer):

> `-R`
> Use the raw value for evaluating the percentage representation. This is the default mode.
>
> `-M`
> Use the mapped volume for evaluating the percentage representation like `alsamixer`, to be more natural for human ear.

Therefore use `amixer -M get Master`.